# How to ignore Transformed WidgetSpan's text width when laying out the lines in RichText?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to move part of the text within `RichText` to occupy the place roughly above the previous word. I figured that the best option for that is to have the following hierarchy:

```
RichText
|
- TextSpan
- WidgetSpan
| |
| - Text
- TextSpan
```

with code like this:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xff696d77),
      fontSize: 30,
    ),
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: "before",
        style: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff6e9ab1)),
      ),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(-10, -20),
          child: const Text(
            "above",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: ' '),
      TextSpan(
        text: "after",
      ),
    ]
  )
)
```

This works almost perfect in re. translation:

[image]

but there's a bunch of white space between `before` and `after` the size of `above`. How do I get rid of it?

What I want to have:

[image]

Comment: Can you include an image how it should look like?

Comment: span will take space, you can apply transform to the last word, but I think it is better to use multi line

Comment: the source text is already multi-line and I’m not too excited about doing the word wrapping manually, though

Comment: the inner space comes from `above` text space, you can try adding transform to the next one too, *transformation before painting its child* . About the result, I till prefer different method like using newline or Stack.

Comment: So to clarify a bit – both before and after are long lines of text, potentially a couple paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was much easier than expected. All it takes is to extend the `WidgetSpan` and not report the child width during the build:

```dart
class _UnsizedWidgetSpan extends WidgetSpan {
  _UnsizedWidgetSpan({required super.child});

  @override
  void build(ui.ParagraphBuilder builder,
      {double textScaleFactor = 1.0, List<PlaceholderDimensions>? dimensions}) {
    assert(debugAssertIsValid());
    assert(dimensions != null);
    final bool hasStyle = style != null;
    if (hasStyle) {
      builder.pushStyle(style!.getTextStyle(textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor));
    }
    assert(builder.placeholderCount < dimensions!.length);
    final PlaceholderDimensions currentDimensions =
        dimensions![builder.placeholderCount];
    builder.addPlaceholder(
      0,  // <-- do not report the width
      currentDimensions.size.height,
      alignment,
      scale: textScaleFactor,
      baseline: currentDimensions.baseline,
      baselineOffset: currentDimensions.baselineOffset,
    );
    if (hasStyle) {
      builder.pop();
    }
  }
}
```